# GridDB SQL Error [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] Failover timed out

Tags: griddb

I intentionally stopped my GridDB cluster and attempt to run SQL command ( `showcontainer` ) on **gs_sh** GridDB shell and got the following errors;

> D20307: An unexpected error occurred while attempting to connect. : msg=[(NoSQL)127.0.0.1:10001,[10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] Failover timed out (trialCount=30, failureMillis=30057, timeoutMillis=30000, reason=[10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0), historySize=30, historyOfTop10(trial, millisFromInitial, millisFromPrev, reason)=[(2, 1004, 1004, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (5, 4012, 1005, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (6, 5015, 1003, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (22, 21042, 1002, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (23, 22044, 1002, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (26, 25048, 1002, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (27, 26050, 1002, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (28, 27052, 1002, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (29, 28054, 1002, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)), (30, 29055, 1001, [10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (pId=0, required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER, LSN=0) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0))]) (NewSQL)127.0.0.1:20001,[10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] Connection problem occurred (retryCount=16, elapsedMillis=15037, failureMillis=15029, queryTimeoutMillis=(not bounded), loginTimeoutMillis=15000, operation=LOGIN, reason=[10008:TXN_CLUSTER_ROLE_UNMATCH] (required={MASTER, FOLLOWER}, actual=SUB_CLUSTER) (address=127.0.0.1:20001, partitionId=0))]

Answer (score 1):

For those who may encounter this kind of error when running SQL commands, These are the following steps to take to fix this error;

1. Confirm your GridDB cluster connection using;

   `gs_stat -u admin/admin | grep Status`

If you get the following result:

```
"clusterStatus": "SUB_CLUSTER",
"nodeStatus": "INACTIVE",
"partitionStatus": "INITIAL"
```

Then your cluster has been stopped and need to be restarted.

1. Restarting your cluster using the command

`gs_joincluster -u admin/admin -w -c myCluster`

2. Verify that you have the cluster running using the command

`gs_stat -u admin/admin | grep Status`

If you get the following result:

```
"clusterStatus": "MASTER",
    "nodeStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "partitionStatus": "NORMAL",
```

Then, you have successfully restarted the cluster and can start running your SQL/TQL commands.